# Reading a registry value to a batch variable, handling spaces in data value

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm struggling to read the value of a registry key into a variable. The registry value contain spaces. In this case I'm trying to get Firefox installed version.

```
C:\Users\ronak>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox ESR" /v CurrentVersion

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox ESR
    CurrentVersion    REG_SZ    45.2.0 ESR (x86 en-GB)
```

The key name, key type, and key value are separated by a series of spaces

For which I wrote following script

```
 For /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox ESR" /v CurrentVersion') Do Set FFversion=%%a
Echo %FFversion%
```

I am getting the out put

```
45.2.0
```

How do I capture entire value of the registry I.e `45.2.0 ESR (x86 en-GB)` and not `45.2.0`

Regards, Ronak.

Comment: `Tokens=3*` is how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox" /v CurrentVersion') DO (
    set FFversion=%%a %%b
)
ECHO %FFversion%
pause
```

I got as result :

```
47.0 (x86 fr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to parse the results.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox" /v CurrentVersion`) DO (
    set appver=%%A %%B
    )
ECHO %appver%
```

Returns

```
47.0 (x86 en-GB)
```